# Writing Edges to Cosmos DB using Cosmos Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb

I have followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-spark) and have created graph vertices in a cosmosDB, but I can't find any documentation on how to create edges between the vertices using the same approach - is this possible?

For info, this is the code used to create the vertices.

```
spark.createDataFrame((("cat-alive", "Schrodinger cat", 2, True), ("cat-dead", "Schrodinger cat", 2, False)))\
  .toDF("id","name","age","isAlive") \
   .write\
   .format("cosmos.oltp")\
   .options(**cfg)\
   .mode("APPEND")\
   .save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, the edge needs specific column headers (_sink and _vertex become the from and to).

```
spark.createDataFrame([(True, "edge_label", 'id_whatever_you_choose', "", "cat-alive", "", "cat-dead")])\
  .toDF('_isEdge', 'label', 'id', '_vertexLabel', '_sink', '_sinkLabel', '_vertexId')\
   .write\
   .format("cosmos.oltp")\
   .options(**cfg)\
   .mode("APPEND")\
   .save()
```